# I am trying to get the string "Mother" to replace the string "string" but I'm getting an error

Tags: objective-c, replace, nsstring

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    NSString *dog=@"Hotdog? I thought you said hotfrog!";
    NSMutableString *mute;

    mute = [NSMutableString stringWithString:dog];
    NSLog(@"%@", mute);

    [mute setString:@"I am a new string "];
    NSLog(@"%@", mute);

    [mute replaceCharactersInRange: NSMakeRange(11, 12) withString: @"mother"];
    NSLog(@"%@", mute);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should definitely throw you an error because your `mute` string length is 17 and your range indicating starting range from 11 to 23 (11+12).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to use the method

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target 
                                    withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

so `target` would be `@"string"` and `replacement` would be `@"Mother"`. So your program could look like this:

```
NSString *originalString = @"I am a new string ";
NSLog(@"Here is the original string: %@", originalString);

NSString *newString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"string" withString:@"Mother"];
NSLog(@"And here is the new string: %@", newString);
```

There are also other similar methods listed [here in the doco](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/20000154-SW25).

---

Note, if you explicitly want to use `NSMutableString` please state so in your question.

---

Note, this was a pretty easy answer to find by [doing a quick Google search](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=nsstring%20replace%20string%20with%20string)

Comment: This is a mutable string; there's no need to create a new object.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It was an `NSString` originally - I say there is no need to turn it into a `NSMutableString` :D

Comment: You can't create an `NSMutableString` directly from a literal. This is obviously a sample program to try out using `NSMutableString`.